# Scheduled data backup from client to server

Tags: c#, java, client-server, backup

Can anyone point out what technologies would be best suited for an application that backs up data from clients to a server?

> The client should choose folders to backup and schedule backups to a server

I would also be interested in how would you start developing/designing, how would you build in the shortest time possible a rudimentary version of the application.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty way on windows?

Shared folders / [Robocopy](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&familyid=9D467A69-57FF-4AE7-96EE-B18C4790CFFD) / Scheduled tasks (or triggered by your app, for that matter)

Nicest way?

Cobian backup with an FTP server

Are you sure you want to develop your own stuff? Is it compulsory to lie within your app?

Answer (score 0):

If I wanted to make a single backup I would use a free backuptool, use Google to find one suitable for your needs

Answer (score 0):

There are many backup apps from something as simple as xcopy to Symantec.  I agree with Vinzz is there really a reason to develop your own?

Answer (score 0):

I just need to develop this kind o application.